# Problemas con el registro de un archivo .tlb

Tags: c#, windows, vb6, windows10

La situación es la siguiente:

He creado un pequeño proyecto de librería de clases en C# que me permita realizar ciertas operaciones. El nombre del archivo creado es, para el ejemplo, **MiFirma.cs**.

Pero como necesito que el componente generado desde C# sea reutilizado en Visual Basic 6.0, era necesario crear un archivo de extensión .tlb. Por eso, usando unas herramientas para generarlo, logré crear los archivos: MiFirma.dll, MiFirma.netmodule, MiFirma.snk y MiFirma.tlb; siendo el requerido para usarlo en Visual Basic 6.0 el archivo final **MiFirma.tlb**.

Luego, como tengo el proyecto de Visual Basic 6.0 en mi equipo, referencio al archivo MiFirma.tlb y funciona con normalidad.

El problema está en utilizar sólo el ejecutable generado desde Visual Basic 6.0 (ej: **MiFirma.exe**), supuestamente referenciado con MiFirma.tlb, en otro equipo que no tiene instalado Visual Basic 6.0 (esa es la idea), carga la aplicación con normalidad, pero cuando quiero utilizar la función del componente MiFirma.tlb, sale el error: "El componente ActiveX no puede crear el objeto".

¿Qué puede estar pasando? Porque estoy utilizando los comandos "regasm.exe", "regtlib.exe", vuelvo a seguir los pasos para "crear el .tlb" directamente en el otro equipo, y nada. De repente lo estaré haciendo incorrectamente.

¡Podrían ayudarme por favor! ¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Instalas/copias junto a tu programa la DLL del ActiveX y lo registras correctamente?

Comment: No es DLL, es un TLB. Y si tengo que registrarlo, ¿cómo tengo que hacerlo?

Comment: Es posible que tu libreria dependa de alguna otra que no se encuentre en el otro equipo?

Comment: Es posible, pero ya no se continuó con el trabajo. Hemos optado por crear los métodos en el mismo lenguaje.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando yo necesitaba si mal no recuerdo hacía lo siguiente:

1. Genero mi dll y junto con el archivo .tlb se sitúa en la ruta C:\windows\system32\ (C:\windows\Syswow64\ para equipos de 64 bits)
2. Registro la dll desde el cmd en modo de administrador C:\windows\system32\regsvr32 C:\windows\system32\nombredll.dll (C:\windows\system32\regsvr32 C:\windows\syswow64\nombredll.dll para equipos de 64 bits)
3. En el proyecto vb6 hago referencia al .tlb y luego compilo para generar el exe
4. Una vez generado el exe del proyecto de vb6 me llevo con el ejecutable los archivos (.dll y .tlb)
5. En el equipo donde va a estar corriendo mi programa también pongo los dos archivos en el C:\windows\system32\ (C:\windows\Syswow64\ para equipos de 64 bits)  y los registro como en el paso 2

Answer (score 1):

amigo, lo que hice fue lo siguiente.

desde el cmd ejecutado como administrador en el equipo donde ejecuto el .exe

busqué la ubicacion del regasm.exe y ejecute la siguiente linea

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>RegAsm.exe C:\Windows\System32\Api.dll /tlb: C:\Windows\System32\Api.tlb

yo copie ambos al system32, la verdad no sé si es necesario, pero ya me funcionó.

me cuentas como te va.

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hola quizás es muy tarde recién lo ví. Eso sucede porque el registro debe hacerse en cada máquina donde se va a utilizar.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/392710)